# How do I show default values prior to triggering ObserveEvent in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In running the below "reduced working code" (RWC), the plot `graph1` only appears when the user hits the optional "SHOW VECTOR" button. This is triggered by renderUI function.

How do I modify this so the plot appears when the App is first invoked, prior to hitting "SHOW VECTOR"? Plot values would reflect the default values of 60 periods (x-axis) and 0.20 (y-axis) (as it does when the plot appears immediately after hitting the SHOW VECTOR button, before the user modifies the plot with inputs into the 2nd matrix that appears in the sidebar panel).

I feel this is due to how renderUI and observeEvent are being used. I am no master here.

And a related issue -- when the App is rerun, all values should return to their default values. But they don't. Run the App, vectorize the variable A by hitting the SHOW VECTOR button (starting with the right column in the input matrix before inputting into left column - minor matrix bug I have the fix for). Check out the global variables, for testing purposes, and they should match your inputs (periods.R, vector_input.R, vector.R). Close the App, reopen it, and don't reset anything, just close it now, and those global variables should have returned to their default settings (A, B, C, D all set to .20, periods from slider input set to 60). But they don't, only periods.R does return to default setting of 60. I'm almost sure this is also due to my bungled use of renderUI/observeEvent.

Here is the RWC (could have reduced it further, but keeping the skeleton-outline will help me adapt any solution to the full working App; the mechanics of the functions can be ignored as they they work fine):

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x) {
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- x                                
  a[,1][a[,1]>y] <- y                   
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA
  b <- c(1,b)
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector <- function(X,Y,Z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, X)
  a[Y] <- Z
  a[seq_len(min(Y)-1)] <- a[min(Y)]
  if(max(Y) < X){a[seq(max(Y)+1, X, 1)] <- 0}
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y
  b <- seq(1:X)
  c <- data.frame(X = b, Z = a)
  return(c)}

vector.final <- function(x,y){vector(x,matrix.validate(y,x)[,1],matrix.validate(y,x)[,2])}

### Shiny code ###
ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
               sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
               matrix1.input("base_input"),
               
               # Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors:
                 useShinyjs(),
                 actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn','Show vector'), 
                 actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn','Hide vector'),
                 uiOutput("Vectors")),
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,helpText("Dynamic model"),plotOutput("graph1")),
          id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  # --- Set reactive input variables 
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)
  
  # --- Link first row of vector input grids to base_input matrix
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y","Z")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  # --- Show performance vector if user elects
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    req(input$showPerfVectorBtn)
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI

  # Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors:
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})

# Show plot:    
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(plot(oe1(),type="b"))
  
# Capture inputs/outputs as global variables: periods.R, vector_input.R, vector_validate.R, vector.R
  observeEvent(periods(),{periods.R <<- periods()})
  observeEvent(base_input(),{base_input.R <<- base_input()})  
  observeEvent(vector_input(),{vector_input.R <<- vector_input()})
  observeEvent(matrix.validate(vector_input(),periods()), 
               {vector_validate.R <<- unique(matrix.validate(vector_input(),periods()))})
  oe1 <- reactive({req(periods(),vector_input())
    vector.final(periods(),vector_input())})
    observeEvent(oe1(),{vector.R <<- oe1()})    
}) # close server

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: For debugging, I suggest removing your `req` calls. It makes it difficult to see the intended reactive chain.

Comment: OK will remove req calls, will simplify the code and edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below resolved code. Main problem was with defined functions; they had to be changed to reflect the differently-dimensioned input matrices that should be being used in calculations. Also renderPlot was incorrectly calling on those same defined functions. It is now corrected in the below final code. Removing `req` per the comment sent me down the right path because it's usage was covering up the underlying issues with the defined functions.

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y  
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA              
  b <- c(1,b)                
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)]
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                       sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
                       matrix1.input("base_input"),
                       useShinyjs(),
                       actionButton('showBtn','Show vector'), 
                       actionButton('hideBtn','Hide vector'),
                       uiOutput("Vectors")),
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,plotOutput("graph1")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)

  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y","Z")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  # --- Show performance vector if user elects
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    req(input$showBtn)
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]),type="b")
    else
      plot(vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input())),type="b")
    ) # close render plot
 }) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```